# How to escape a badly-named property using PowerShell in Azure Web App app settings

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, hashtable, appsettings

I have a set of Azure Web App properties gathered by

`$properties = (Invoke-AzureRMResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup`
`-ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/Config -Name $Site/appsettings`
`-Action list -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force).Properties`

Also, I've made a hash table to store these properties

`$hashtable = @{}`
`$properties | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | % { $hashtable[$_.Name] = $properties.($_.Name) }`

The problem I've faced is to change the badly formatted property to a new value:

`PS C:\> $hashtable`
`Name                           Value`
`----                           -----`
`AzureAd:ClientId               XXXXXX-1621-42ff-85cd-XXXXXXXXX`

```
PS C:\> $hashtable.AzureAd:ClientId = "YYYYYY-1621-42ff-85cd-YYYYYYYY"

At line:1 char:14
+ $hashtable.AzureAd:ClientId = "YYYYYY-1621-42ff-85cd-YYYYYYY ...
+              ~~~~
Unexpected token ':ClientId' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

So the command `Set-AzureRMWebApp -Name $Site -AppSettings $hashtable` isn't needed.

Is there a chance to escape the poor property in order to execute the script or should I next be careful when choosing the right app settings name\variable?

Comment: Enclose the property within double quotes - `$hashtable."AzureAd:ClientId" = "YYYYYY-1621-42ff-85cd-YYYYYYYY"`

Comment: Too easy :) Thanks!

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh: Can you please turn your comment into an answer? Perhaps also suggest single quotes, given that there's nothing expand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enclose the properties within double quotes like this -

```
$hashtable."AzureAd:ClientId" = "YYYYYY-1621-42ff-85cd-YYYYYYYY"
```

You can also use single quotes(`''`) since there is no variable to be substituted in your property -

```
$hashtable.'AzureAd:ClientId' = "YYYYYY-1621-42ff-85cd-YYYYYYYY"
```